# How to avoid some required fields to be checked depending by a radio button

Tags: forms

Maybe is better to explain with an example.

I have a form with a radio button with YES/NO items.

When a user select NO the fields below the radio button are disabled, while when he click on YES, the fields are enabled.

```
<form id="myForm">
  <h3>Test Form</h3>
  <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="needabikesino0" onclick="enableDisableAll();" /> Yes
  <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="needabikesino1" onclick="enableDisableAll();" /> No
  <p><input type="text" id="numerobiciclette" name="mybikes" placeholder="bike numbers" disabled /></p>
  <p><input type="text" id="altezza" name="myheight" placeholder="my height" disabled /></p>
  <p><input type="text" id="numerocaschi" name="myhelmets" placeholder="my helmets" disabled /></p>
</form>

function enableDisableAll() {
  cb1 = document.getElementById('needabikesino0').checked;
  document.getElementById('numerobiciclette').disabled = !cb1;
  document.getElementById('altezza').disabled = !cb1;
  document.getElementById('numerocaschi').disabled = !cb1;
}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/dforce/0u13z7md/

The PROBLEM is:

When the user choose NO on the radio button, is not possible to send the form because the fields are compulsory.

I need the form to be sent even when the user choose NO.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the field readOnly?

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_readonly.asp

Comment: Hello, sorry if I have explained in a bad way...

I am able to enable or disabled fields depending by the choice of the radio button (YES or NO).

The problem comes when an user click on SEND button.

In this case, the system check if all the compulsory fields are filled, but the problem comes because it consider the ones disabled too! 

So it doesn't allow the user to send the form.